# HAML loop binding late for partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I'm trying to put loop as partial inside loop like below:

```
%ul
- halls.each do |hall, children|
    %li
        = link_to_unless_current hall.name, hall
        = render partial: 'hall_structure', :locals => { halls: children } if children.present?
```

Partial hall_structure:

```
%ul
- halls.each do |hall, children|
    %li
        = link_to_unless_current hall.name, hall
        = render partial: 'hall_structure', :locals => { halls: children } if children.present?
```

But somehow the output is like this:

```
<ul>
                      <li>
                        <a href="/halls/5">Main Hall</a>
                        <ul></ul>
                        </li><li>
                          <a href="/halls/1">Conference Hall</a>

                        </li>
                        <li>
                          <a href="/halls/4">Exhibition Hall</a>

                        </li>

                    </ul>
```

Is there a reason why it's not putting in partial loop as inner loop under the first `li`?

Comment: Hmm... Your partials above look the same.  Is this correct?

Comment: @CDub I tried changing the variable names and also I want the `ul` list to go under 'li' but it seems `li` gets wrapped around the second `ul`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the indentation?

```
%ul
  - halls.each do |hall, children|
```

Also make sure that's the real output. Not the final xml that your browser rendered. Many web browsers try to fix mal formed html. And it seems to me it might be happening here.